# Myriad of (relatively minor) issues on my rMBP in the last few days

Tags: icloud, macbook-pro

Not sure how to generalize this, but my rMBP 15" 2014 has started having several weird issues in the past few days:

- Typing freezes (briefly) in Notes
- Searching “Keychain” from spotlight returns some results but NOT “Keychain Access”
- Xcode stops building files because “too many open files on system”, fixed by restart
- Mail autocomplete doesn’t work -> Restart Mail, freezes on open -> Restart again, same -> Open Internet Accounts in System Prefs, freezes -> Restart computer, works
- Beachball opening folder from Dock -> Downloads (about 10 seconds)

None of these issues seems to stay for long. For example, if I search Spotlight for "Keychain" now, it returns the correct result.

More info, I'm running 10.10.1, 16gb RAM, my 500gb hard drive is about 2/5 free. I clean installed Yosemite about 6 months ago too.

Does anyone know this might be? Hardware issue, like failing motherboard or something? Or (hopefully) some kind of software bug?

Comment: First place I'd look would be Activity Monitor. Memory pressure, any process looking exceptionally busy, mds/mdworker indexing etc, how much Swap is being used. My old MP started to get a bit like that - my 'fix' was an SSD & another 16GB RAM.

Comment: Clean installed Yosemite 6 months ago? Yosemite was beta then!

Comment: You're right, it was definitely not in beta. Looks like it was released mid-October, so must have been around early November.

Answer (score 1):

We've had a couple of machines at work in a similar state, they were brought back to normal operation by starting in **safe boot** then moving the **Containers** folder from the user's **Library** folder to the desktop. This has the effect of clearing the startup caches, performing a disk check and resetting sandboxed applications back their default settings.

A new Containers folder will be automatically created. Any applications that have lost important data after moving the Containers folder can be restored by copying the relevant folder from the old Containers folder to the new one - I always make a copy of the ARD folder as any custom UNIX commands will be lost otherwise.

As a matter of course I would also want to run a disk permissions check and give the drive structure a check with DiskWarrior.